# Dynamic parameters in Azure Pipeline base on another parameter value?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

Currently my UI pipeline before running is like this:

[image]

As you can see I have "Flow File Path" which its value is path to my json file in the repo.

My question is can I parse that `testfile.json` and add more parameters in the UI? Because I need the value from the user enter in before running the pipeline (possibly sensitive value).

I searched for a while but seem like not available, is there any solution for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is much nicer and more convenient to use Azure Key Vault, especially if we are talking about sensitive data.

[image: Azure Key Vault in azure release pipeline]

Reference: [Use Azure Key Vault secrets in Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)

Reference2: [Add & use variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic)

You can't upload a json file as a release variable from the UI.

Comment: Not really what I want, but this is the only option I can use right now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot. These values must be defined in the YAML file and can only depend on a few things like Environments and Stages.